# AS3: Post to Facebook Wall - Error #2032

Tags: facebook, actionscript-3, facebook-graph-api

I am currently developing an app with which visitors of an event can take pictures using a webcam and upload them to Facebook using an AS3-application. I know I can connect to Facebook, because I can log the user out using the API and I can get all the information. The problem is that I can't post to their wall for some reason. I keep getting the following error:

```
error #2032: stream error. url: https://graph.facebook.com/********/feed
```

I use the following code to post to Facebook:

```
private function postFB(e:Event=null):void {
    var _params:Object = new Object();

    _params.uid = Facebook.getAuthResponse().uid;
    _params.access_token = Facebook.getAuthResponse().accessToken;
    _params.message = "I was at the Thanksgiving Day Event.";
    //_params.picture = _bitmap;

    Facebook.api("/me/feed", postComplete, _params, "POST");
}
```

As I've said before, I know I am connected to facebook because if I change "POST" to "GET" in my api-call, I get all the information of my account. I have the correct permissions as far as I know (read_stream, publish_stream, user_photos). I use GraphAPI_Web_1_8_1.swc as an api.

The documentation on the entire api is very poor, so I am trying to figure out the problem. It's been a few years since I've tried any of this, so my code has probably aged too far by now. So, any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`publish_stream` is deprecated (since years?), you need to use `publish_actions`.

If that does not work, make sure the Access Token includes all the permissions, you can test this in the Debugger: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/

Side note: AS3 is not getting used very often anymore, the last version of the the AS3 SDK is from 2011. It may be a good idea to switch to the JavaScript SDK.

Comment: That was indeed the problem! Thanks! :) I'll accept your answer in 8 minutes, I can't accept just yet!

Comment: oh, i just added some more information. well, glad i could help :)

Comment: I was very comfortable working with AS3 until Flash got pretty much discontinued. So that's why I still program using that. :) But I am a teacher now, so I don't program often anymore. I'll keep it in mind anyways and I'll change to Javascript SDK if I have to do anything like this again! :)

Comment: One more question maybe.. You don't happen to know how to upload a bitmap from AS3 to Facebook using graph? :) I have added the "photo_upload"-permission, but it doesn't seem to work :) When I remove the comment in my code with the _params.image, the app connects to FB, doesn't throw an error, but never reaches my complete-handler :) If I leae it in comment, I can post to my wall

Comment: phew, i know i did that a very long time ago with flash, but i have no clue anymore. i think the best you can do is upload it it to your server and use the api with the absolute url.

Comment: Maybe that will be easiest, using php! ;) I'll try it, thanks!